# Print ArrayList that depends on other ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

I have an array of ArrayList.
  For example, 
            `array[0] = a b c d
               array[1] = e f g h 
               array[2] = i`

Every ArrayList in the array must be printed out, but some items are dependent on items in other ArrayLists, which must be printed first.

```
level 1 - array[0] = a b* c d
level 2 - array[1] = e* f g h 
level 3 - array[2] = i
```

The letters with the star next to it must be printed out with the items in the next level. In this case, b must include e, f, g, h since all those letters are in the next level (level2). Since e also has a star next to it, it must first print out i because i is in the next level (level3). The result is as following:

```
  a
  b
    -e
      -i
    -f
    -g
    -h
  c
  d
```

I have a HashMap to keeps track of which letters require printing of the next level. So, (b, 2), (e, 3) are in the map since b depends on level 2, and 3 depends on level 3.

This is what I've tried

```
    public String buildString(int level, String word) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        sb.append('-');
    }
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(word);
    return sb.toString();
}

public void printList() {
    ArrayList<String> firstLevel = allLevels[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < firstLevel.size(); i++) {
        String word = firstLevel.get(i);
        System.out.println(word);
        if(map.containsKey(word)) {
            ArrayList<String> anotherLevel = allLevels[map.get(word)];
            for(int j = 0; j < anotherLevel.size(); j++) {
                String word2 = anotherLevel.get(j);
                System.out.println(buildString(map.get(word), word2));
                if(map.containsKey(word2)) {
                    ArrayList<String> anotherAnotherLevel = allLevels[map.get(word2)];
                    for(int k = 0; k < anotherAnotherLevel.size(); k++) {
                        String word3 = anotherAnotherLevel.get(k);
                        System.out.println(buildString(map.get(word2), word3));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields the correct result, but it is not dynamic since it does not work for all cases. How would I go about making the code more dynamic? I'm assuming recursion will be needed...

Comment: And where is the code, which you have tried?

Comment: What is your question?  What do you expect us to do for you?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp Just added my code. Forgot to do it earlier.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I edited the post and made it more clear.

Comment: It certainly looks like recursion would be a good technique, although not strictly necessary.  Try refactoring the repeated code from `printList` to a recursive method.  That method will need a `String` parameter, where you can pass `word`, or `word2` or whatever.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem hey my apologies for the late reply. I figured it out a couple of days ago. Thanks for the help!